# How to distinguish same jars started from different directories?

Tags: java, linux, process, jar

I started several (eight) jar files with the same name from different directories and different config files.

Now I have to kill a specific one. But neither jps and ps gives enough information to distinguish them. How could I find out which java process was started from which directory?

Platform : linux (ubuntu server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the man page it says: use option e to show the environment variables after the command.
so try using the 'e' option:
`ps e`

you can then look for PWD variable. I hope this will help.

Comment: 'ps e' gives a very ugly output but showed the PWD variable, thanks!
I have found a nicer command after your hint : 
pwdx <processid> shows you just the PWD.